# A vertical black bar appears in the middle of the element at different resolutions when using a gradient

Tags: html, css, gradient, linear-gradients

A vertical black bar appears in the middle of the element at different resolutions when using a gradient. It's appears in "webkit" browsers (Firefox is an exception).

My HTML code:

```html
<div class="button">Button</div>
```

CSS code:

```css
.button {
  background: #007FEE;
  background: linear-gradient(
135deg, transparent 10px, #007FEE 0) top left, linear-gradient(
225deg, transparent 10px, #007FEE 0) top right;
  background-size: 50% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #000;
  height: 40px;
}
```

[image: Button with black vertical line at center]

Here is that second `background` property is reason why it's appears (linear-gradient).

Thanks in advance for answers! Sorry about my english.

Comment: I found a solution!

Just resized `background-size` from 50% to higher than 50% (example: 51%).

Comment: That's likely to be rounding issues, the 50% width of the left half getting rounded down so that you end up with widths of one pixel less than necessary. Specify a _slightly_ greater width for the left half, like `background-size: 50.01% 100%;`

Comment: @CBroe Thanks a lot. We are answered at the same time. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because of `background-size: 50% 100%;`

Just change the value to be greater than 50%.

Try: `background-size: 51% 100%;`